# Change shortcode value by jquery in WP Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this code on the WP Editor

```
<p>[vc_row][vc_column][le_page_grid le_page_grid_layout="1"][/vc_column][/vc_row]</p>
```

and i have two radio buttons on the meta box

```
<label><input type="radio" name="layout" value="1" /> Layout 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="layout" value="2" /> Layout 2</label>
```

My question is how can i change the value of `le_page_grid_layout="1"` to `le_page_grid_layout="2"` using jquery when i click on Layout 2 and vice versa.

Thanks in advance